# Slick 3.1.x CRUD: how to extract the entire up-to-date inserted row?

Tags: scala, slick

Basically I'd like to using Slick and in a generic DAO model-independent way, insert and at the same time retrieve the most up to date entity row data.

I previously asked this question [Slick 3.1.x CRUD: how to extract the inserted row id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861900/slick-3-1-x-crud-how-to-extract-the-inserted-row-id) and at the end managed to get it working. However, that approach is not optimal because of the following reasons:

- It assumes that each Model has an `id` attribute and this might not always be the case. This works only for strong entities and not for e.g. one-to-many weak entities and of course having to name the `id` always as `id` is a nuisance.
- There are potentially other fields that get populated upon insertion e.g. a possible `modified` timestamp or whatever custom database trigger modifications and not only `id` or `modified`

Therefore, I'd like to find a solution that inserts the new entity and at the same time fetches out the whole new Entity row and not just the `id`. So instead of doing:

```
val insertQuery = User returning User.map(_.id) into ((row, id) => row.copy(id = id))
```

Have something more like:

```
val insertQuery = User returning User.map(_) into ((row, ???) => row.copy(??? = ???))
```

Comment: `User returning User.map(_.id) ` can only be used if id is the primary key and auto increment key. Also you cannot return every column. You will get runtime exception if you try returning any other column exception auto increment, primary key ... To do the things you are thinking of .. insert query is not the place

Comment: How is this use-case covered in Slick? e.g. if I don't have a table that contains id or for that matter an auto-increment id?

Comment: @GiovanniAzua after succesful insertion ... you can query back the values inserted.

Comment: @GiovanniAzua  you can only select a row if it has some composite primary key meaning .. some column combination should uniquely identify the row

Comment: Indeed but I wanted to avoid the resulting roundtrip. Anyhow I had to split the dao into, normal dao that applies to any model and dao that applies to a strong entity that therefore has autogenerated id and create should also fetch the id (so it can be located/updated later)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we did was to have a base class for classic, syntetic, autoincrement ID `BaseDaoAutoInc`. For other cases we used other base class which defined (among other) a method like:
`findById` (whatever this ID actually was).

So for cases where we wanted to have full row fetched after insert (e.g. when we had some values generated by database e.g. current timestamp etc) what we generally did was this:

`(tableQuery += newEntry).flatMap(_ => findById(newEntry.??))`

Above assumes you don't have autogenerated key (and you know it during insertion time). If you have generated key AND need to read object after insertion than you would need to add this `returning` part to above code to fetch autogenerated ID first and then full row.

Comment: Wow cool idea! will try it and accept later :) I also ended separating the Dao into Strong Entities and Weak Entities (I assume all Strong entities have an auto-increment `id` primary key) but your separation and naming for the separation makes more sense! Thank you so much for sharing!

Comment: One detail ... isn't this line necessary before: `val insertQuery = tableQuery returning tableQuery.map(_.id) into ((row, id) => row.copy(id = id))` because your `newEntry.id` is not updated in memory after doing the `+=`

Comment: Yes, it is not updated. This is what I mentioned here: `Above assumes you don't have autogenerated key (and you know it during insertion time).`

Comment: yes but they can be easily combined by using in your answer `insertQuery` instead of `queryTable`. I will test it now can't :)

Comment: Pressed ENTER to quick:

If I'd have autogenerated id AND would like to fetch row after insert I'd do something like you mentioned above plus part in `flatMap`.

Something like this:
`((tableQuery returning tableQuery.map(_.id) into ((row, id) => row.copy(id = id))) += newEntry).flatMap(row => findById(row.id))`

Comment: What is the signature of your findById? because I get a compiler error on the flatMap saying that it expects a DBIOAction and not a Future[Option[E]] as I have it ...

Comment: It should be simply your *ID* - whatever that is. Also if you have `Future` you probably already run `db.run` (otherwise you wouldn't have `Future`). If you paste your code I can try to see what's the problem.

Comment: The error is this `found: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[E]], required: slick.dbio.DBIOAction[?,?,?]` and the code you can find it here: https://github.com/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala/blob/master/app/dao/GenericDaoAutoIncImpl.scala#L25

Comment: OK - just change your implementation of `findById` to this:
`override def findById(id: PK): DBIO[Option[E]] = tableQuery.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption` (returns DBIO instead of Future).

Generally using slick you don't want your DAO to return Future. It should return DBIO. DBIO will be converted to Future by your business logic. Otherwise (if you use Future on DAO level) you will loose composability (you won't be able to compose multiple operations into single transaction).

That's pretty much the nature of Slick.